# How can I convert an .rtf or .doc document to LaTeX?

Tags: latex, ms-word, rtf, docx

Unfortunately, I can't use rtf2latex2e because it says that DropUNIX "no longer supports the classic environment". I barely know what I'm doing otherwise, besides dropping my .rtf file onto the DropUNIX program.

What else can I use? I don't mind which type of file it is I'm converting to LaTeX (.doc would also be OK, as long as it keeps my formatting).

I am using Mac OS 10.5.8.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/141043/converting-a-word-document-to-latex-format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Open Office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) can. Download [it](http://download.openoffice.org/).

Comment: That sounds simple. Do I have to download Writer2Latex for it? I can't find any kind of "export to latex" function, like I was naively expecting.

Comment: `Menu` -> `File` -> `Export...` and `File format` is `LaTeX`

Comment: Make sure also that download writer2latex from http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/ . Open Office doesn't come by default with the LaTeX writer. Click on the file writer4latex.oxt in the writer2latex114alpha.zip that you download.

Answer (score 4):

See the [fmtconv](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=fmtconv) question on the UK TeX FAQ, or, more specifically, the page on [Converters from PC Textprocessors to LaTeX - Overview](http://www.tug.org/utilities/texconv/pctotex.html), which is specifically about this question and has many many examples. This general list of [word-processor filters](http://www.w3.org/Tools/Word_proc_filters.html) may help too.

Answer (score 2):

[UnRTF](http://www.gnu.org/software/unrtf/unrtf.html) claims to be able to convert RTF to LaTeX as well as other formats (e.g. HTML). It claims to support HTML best, so perhaps RTF->HTML->LaTeX (e.g. with html2latex) might work better. I haven't actually tried any of this though.

Answer (score 2):

Make your rtf/doc document into docx, and convert it using [docx2tex](http://docx2tex.codeplex.com/).

You need the System.IO.Packaging .NET class to get this to work, which is no problem if you are using Windows, and is in principle supported by Mono if you are not.  If anyone has success doing this with Mono, I'd like to hear of your experiences: this didn't work a year or so ago, but their implementation of that class has improved since then.

I say more about the utility in an answer at [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-can-i-import-an-exam-or-assignment-from-word-into-latex/435#435).  Suffice it to say that I consider this by far the cleanest, most Latex-friendly option out there.

Comment: @RaytheonLiszt: Thanks, good to hear this unduly neglected piece of software is getting some attention.  I add a link in my answer to a tex.sx answer of mine with some more info.